# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier using Let

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Node version 16

Discord API version 12

Sorry guys, me again!  So this is the SyntaxError I'm getting with a Discord Bot:

```
/home/container/settings/configuration.js:82
        let stats = {
        ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:7:82)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
```

This is the file that is causing the issue:

```js
module.exports = {
    BOT_SETTINGS: {
        BOT_TOKEN: 'X',
        YT_API_KEY: 'X',
        COMMAND_PREFIX: '?',
        EMBED_COLOR: 'BLUE',
        MUTE_ROLE: '841079005892968458',
        BANNED_WORDS: ['retard', 'nigger'],
        BYPASS_ROLES: ['802711739006582846'],
        BANNED_LINKS: ['www.', '.com', '.net', '.gov', '.co', '.uk', '.gg', '.live'],
        BYPASS_LINKS_ROLES: ["802711739006582846"],
        Member_Count_Channel: '809569469030596648',
        Guild_ID: '802700035544317972',
        Kick_On_Warnings: true,
        Warnings_Until_Kick: '5',
        Time_Muted: '1m',
        LOCALE: 'en',
        Roles_On_Join: ['803388467588628490']
    },
    VERIFICATION: {
        Enabled: false,
        Verify_Channel: 'CHANNELID',
        Verify_Role: 'ROLEID',
        Role_To_Remove: 'ROLEID'
    },
    USER_DMS: {
        Enabled: true,        
        Dm_Category: '809570230611083275',
        Dms: 'new-dm-{user}',
        Dm_Channel_Name: 'new-dm-{user}',
        View_Dmchannels_Roles:['802711739006582846']
    },
    Ping_Prevention: {
        Enabled: true,
        Enabled_Types: 'user',
        Max_Channel_Pings: '5',
        Max_Role_Pings: '5',
        Max_User_Pings: '5',
        Max_Pings: '10',
        Punishment: 'kick',
        Bypass_Roles: ['802711739006582846']
    },
    LOCKDOWN_KICK: {
        Enabled: true,
        Kick_Message: '{server} is currently in LOCKDOWN MODE! We have kicked you for now, please try joining back later {member}. '
    },
    LEVELING_SYSTEM: {
        Enabled: true, 
        Remove_XP_On_Leave: true,
        Level_Up_Message: '{user} has just reached level {level}!',
        Level_Up_Channel_ID: '856158284338692096'
    },
    LOGGING: {
        Report_Channel: '848548626804375562',
        Ban_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Unban_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Kick_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Warn_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Mute_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Lock_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Ticket_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Moderation_Channel_Logs: '848548626804375562',
        Server_Updates: '848548626804375562',
        Voice_Updates: '848548626804375562'
    },
    TICKET_SYSTEM: {
        TICKET_CATEGORY: 'CATEGORY_ID',
        SUPPORT_TEAM_ROLES: 'ROLEID',
    },
    GREETING_SYSTEM: {
        Enabled: true,
        Welcome_Channel: '808727656378925056',
        Welcome_Type: 'card',
        Welcome_Cards_Image_Link: 'https://i.ibb.co/VmGzHKv/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.png',
        Welcome_Message: 'Welcome {member} to the server, You are member {joinPosition}!',
        Welcome_Embed: {
            title: '{member.username} has just joined the server!',
            description: 'Welcome {member} to the server, You are member {joinPosition}!',
            color: 'blue'
        }

        let stats = {
            serverID: 'X',
            totalUsers: "858369874110971914",
            onlineUsers: "858370257797513236",
            onlineStaff: "858370529902985227"
        }
        client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
            if(member.guild.id  !== stats.serverID) return;
            client.channels.cache.get(stats.total).setName(`Total Users: ${member.guild.memberCount}`);
            client.channels.cache.get(stats.member).setName(`Online Users: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size}`,
            client.channels.cache.get(stats.member).setName(`Online Users: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has ('802711739006582846') && m.presence.status === 'online').size}`))
        })
           
        client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
            if(member.guild.id  !== stats.serverID) return;
            client.channels.cache.get(stats.total).setName(`Total Users: ${member.guild.memberCount}`);
            client.channels.cache.get(stats.member).setName(`Online Users: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.presence.status === 'online').size}`,
            client.channels.cache.get(stats.member).setName(`Online Users: ${member.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has('802711739006582846') && m.presence.status === 'online').size}`))
        })
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the section of the index that is referred to in the error:

```js
require('./structures/Guild')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Collection, Client, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { Manager } = require('@lavacord/discord.js')
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const { BOT_TOKEN, EMBED_COLOR, MUTE_ROLE, YT_API_KEY, COMMAND_PREFIX, STATS } = require("./settings/configuration").BOT_SETTINGS;
const db = require('quick.db')
const path = require("path");
const logSymbols = require('log-symbols');
const Enmap = require('enmap');
const Tickets = new Enmap({ name: 'tickets' });
const i18n = require('i18n');
```

Any advise/assistance greatly appreciated!  I thought that adding Stats into line 7 would fix it, but it hasn't, so have left it in for reference purposes.

Comment: What are the lines of code *before* `let stats = {`?

Comment: look at the 81 lines of code above it for issues

Comment: What is the environment you're running in? Is it an es6 compatible environment? Are you trying to run it in an es5 environment without transpiling through babel or other means?

Comment: Edit posted with full code

Comment: You can't run arbitrary code within an object literal declaration, which is what you're attempting to do. It's a list of `key: value` pairs, not a function block.

Comment: OK, so how would I go about fixing that, then, please?  This has been bugging me for 96 hours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On object literal (`GREETING_SYSTEM` in this case) can consist only of name:value pairs, you are initially doing that, but then you just begin declaring a variable with `let`, which is the `unexpected identifier`. Instead, you just need to keep going with name:value pairs:

```
GREETING_SYSTEM: {
    Enabled: true,
    Welcome_Channel: '808727656378925056',
    Welcome_Type: 'card',
    Welcome_Cards_Image_Link: 'https://i.ibb.co/VmGzHKv/wwwwwwwwwwwwwwww.png',
    Welcome_Message: 'Welcome {member} to the server, You are member {joinPosition}!',
    Welcome_Embed: {
        title: '{member.username} has just joined the server!',
        description: 'Welcome {member} to the server, You are member {joinPosition}!',
        color: 'blue'
    },

    stats : {
        serverID: 'X',
        totalUsers: "858369874110971914",
        onlineUsers: "858370257797513236",
        onlineStaff: "858370529902985227"
    }

...
}
```

If you need to declare variables or invoke other functions, you'll need to use a function or class construct instead of an object literal.

Comment: Thank you!!  That solved the first part, however I am now getting this:
```
/home/container/settings/configuration.js:88
        client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
        ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    ... 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:7:82)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
```

Comment: @Delta_Bravo92 It's the same problem, just with the next part of that object. You can only set name:value pairs within an object literal. If you want to do more, use a function declaration or a class, but not an object literal.